# Find #ID from handler with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, posting

How can I find an `#[ID]` using jQuery?

I have a handler that checks some info, I'm checking with jQuery if there is found a ID...
But it always give back "Nothing" and it gives me the errors so it mean that there are errors!

I do it on this way...

jQuery:

```
posting.done(function(data){
    var warnings = $(data).find('.warnings');

    $('form#gastenboek').append(data);

    if (warnings.length > 0) {
        alert("errors")
    } else {
        alert("Nothing");
    }
});
```

Handler:

```
if (!empty($warning) && isset($warning))
{
    foreach($warning as $warning)
    {
        echo "<span id='warnings' style='color:orange;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-flag'></span><a style='color:orange;'>" . $warning . "</a><br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the console say when you add this line `console.log(data)`, right after the line `posting.done(function(data){`

Comment: @LinkinTED Did it just got a this result: <span style='color:#a94442;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign errors'></span><a style='color:#a94442;'>Het berichten veld mag niet leeg zijn.</a><br> ---- So it should be given alert("errors");

Comment: If everything is okay (so no errors/ warnings), what does the console then say?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are using the `attr()` method in the wrong place as it should contain an *attribute* as the first argument. And since there is no element which has an attribute `#warnings`, you'll be getting `null`.

Secondly, there can be *only one element* in the DOM with a particular `id`, unless you specify it as an array by providing `[]` with the id. So searching the DOM with `.find()` will return only the first matched element.

Hence, you should implement a `class` *warnings* on the elements that your `data` returns. Then use jQuery's `.find()` which searches for elements having that particular *warnings* class:

```
var warnings = $(data).find('.warnings');

if(warnings.length > 0){
     alert("warnings");
} else {
     alert("nothing");
}
```

Comment: console.log your `data` please.

Comment: I got this in my console: <span style='color:#a94442;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign errors'></span><a style='color:#a94442;'>Het berichten veld mag niet leeg zijn.</a><br>

Comment: You said `but still not working good`, which part exactly is not working now. Meanwhile, I see that you have removed the `id` and added the class `errors`, so your Javascript should change accordingly as : `var warnings = $(data).find('.errors');`. Have you changed it?

Comment: It still keeps saying `Nothing` so it say there are never errors

Comment: Your Javascript should change accordingly as : `var warnings = $(data).find('.errors');`. Have you changed it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **[`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)**

```
var warnings = $(data).find('#warnings');
```

**Note :** `Id` should be unique , use `class` instead

**PHP:**

```
if (!empty($warning) && isset($warning))
{
    foreach($warning as $warning)
    {
        echo "<span style='color:orange;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-flag warnings'></span><a style='color:orange;'>" . $warning . "</a><br>";
        //                                                                 --^-- adding class
    }
}
```

**jQuery :**

```
posting.done(function(data){
    var warnings = $(data).find('.warnings');

    $('form#gastenboek').append(data);

    if (warnings.length > 0) {
    //           --^-- getting count of elements
        alert("warnings")
    } else {
        alert("Nothing");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thx but now it says always that there are errors! :s

Comment: @Lenap use `if (warnings.length)` as condition

Comment: I tried also not the solution, and u used 2 classes by the  php echo line. so that can not be it